# How can i use both folder path and file name in c# itextsharp?

Tags: c#, sql, itext

I have the following piece of code:

```
private void GeneratePDF()
        {

            string selectPath = "select * from PDFLocation";
            SqlCommand comm = con.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = selectPath;
            con.Open();
            Int32 LocPath = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

                string cln = NumCl.Text;
                string OrderID = NrComanda.Text;
                string DataAzi = dateTimePicker1.Text;
                string FileName = OrderID + "-" + cln + "-" + DataAzi + ".pdf";
                string fullpath = Path.Combine(LocPath.ToString(), FileName);

                Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 42, 35);
                PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
//-----PDF code after-----
}
```

The problem here is that i have a textbox which retrieves the pdf folder location path from a folder dialog and sends it to database. Now i want to retrieve the path stored in the database using this code so i can save the file there. If i use FileName variable instead of fullpath in the FileStream, it works but the file goes to the project folder, which i do not want. With fullpath in the FileStream like it is in the current code, it throws the error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\cloud\source\repos\Project\Project\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0\1\36-UserFile-14.12.2021.pdf'.'
```

Please tell me how to use both folder path and file name in the FileStream or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: According to the error message, some part of the path is not found. Thus, consider creating the directories of the path before putting some file there.

Comment: Yes, the error is generated because fullpath variable contains 2 arguments. One is the folder location, and the second is the file name variable above (FileName). In the FileStream there is only one argument (fullpath) which includes both. The program see the fullpath as only folder path. The question is how can i use both?